# C++ Regular Expression not Working w/ PCRE Expression?

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following code:

```
  include <regex>
  include <string>
  TCHAR basePath[MAX_PATH];
  GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, basePath);

  wstring test(&basePath[0]); //convert to wstring
  string test2(test.begin(), test.end()); //and convert to string.

  std::regex rBase("(.*my-dir)");
  std::smatch sm;
  std::regex_match(test2, sm, rBase);
```

However, sm always returns empty

Basically if I have the following directory structure:

```
E:\foo\bar\baz\my-dir\post1\dir2
```

I need to return

```
"E:\foo\bar\baz\my-dir"
```

The regex seems to work if I run it though, say, python or javascript, but not here in C++

What am I missing or what are some alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be confusing the PCRE regex library with the one that comes with the C++11 standard. The built in C++11 regex only works in more recent compilers. PCRE is not part of the C++ standard so you need to add the PCRE libraries separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::regex_match` checks whether the whole string matches the regex, not just any part of it.

Use `std::regex_search` instead of `std::regex_match` or use a regex that matches the whole string, such as `"(.*my-dir).*"`, and extract the submatch with `sm[1].str()`.